# How to find the position-specific weight matrix (PSWM) for a list of genes having different sizes?

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins, sequence-analysis, computation

Wiki has the algorithm for finding position-specific weight matrix (PSWM) for a list of nucleotide sequences having an equal number of nucleotide. How do we find the PSSM for a list of nucleotide sequences having different sizes?

Answer (score 3):

If your sequences are different lengths, this implies a gapped alignment with insertions/deletions. This is not possible with a regular PSSM, so you have to create a separate PSSM for each group of homologous sequences of the same sequence length.

The alternative is to use a different approach that allows gaps like profile HMMs (as implemented in HMMER3 or HH-Suite3).